# Kubernetes - master to worker node communication using nginx with dynamic url - Kubernetes service

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

We have one Kubernetes master server and more than 100 worker nodes that connected to the master using kubeadm join.

Frontend application deployed in master server and we want to call the worker nodes API. We have given each worker node API a unique name.

**Problem**: we want to call the api using nginx (the angular application that is in the master component) using the proxy pass with dynamic routing. How we can achieve this in Nginx Kubernetes?

```
for example - 

http://example.com/nodeapi/workernodename/apiendpoints 

http://example.com/nodeapi/newyork/Uploadvideo  -> This request must be redirected to newyork worker node. we have provided the worker node name dynamic to URL. 

http://example.com/nodeapi/chicago/Uploadvideo  -> This request must be redirected to Chicago worker node service from the master component. we have provided the worker node name dynamic to URL.
```

```
# This is a sample for a better understanding of the question.

location  ~ ^/nodeapi/(.*)$ {     
         proxy_set_header Host      $host:$server_port;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_pass   http://worker-$1-api-service.operations-portal.svc.cluster.local:4003;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: I have solved this problme using below  `location ~ ^/nodeapi/(.*)/(.*)$ {
    resolver 10.96.0.10 ipv6=off;
    proxy_set_header Host      $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://worker-$2-api-service.default.svc.cluster.local:4003/nodeapi/$1;
    }`

Comment: You [can post this as an answer and then accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so other people can see this and use if they have similar use cases.